# Who caused Rize to die?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

In the first episode, someone threw the crane in order to kill Rize, however that also prompted in having to save Kaneki from totally being devoured/killed .

That was the point from where everything basically took off.

Was the fall of crane just a coincidence or was it deliberately caused by someone in an attempt to kill Rize and if so, who could have it been?

Comment: I am not 100 percent sure who is behind it, but I have couple of guesses: 1. V organization - based on Tokyo Ghoul:re chapter 64 Rize was a member of V and escaped them. 2. Aogiri Tree with doctor Kanou, to get rid of her and get her organs for experiments 3. Clowns - because they like to wreak havoc 4. Anteiku - Yoshimura wanted peace and she was getting to much attention from CCG

Comment: @anaksamea Yes, your guesses are on point and one of them must be responsible, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Manga near the very end Tokyo ghoul, Kaneki remembers the incident, and it was shown that

> The Ghoul Group called the clowns did it as One of them, Souta, was there.

The specific incident summary on the [Wiki](http://tokyoghoul.wikia.com/wiki/Steel_Beam_Incident) confirms this.

The reasons why are not clear yet in TG:RE, as there are several groups that could have been the reason why it happened, or it could have been spur of the moment.